# Constructing mixed text/tag element

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I am trying to convert some code that is building XML in a StringBuilder to using dom4j.

Part of the code is generating something structured similar to this:

```
<foo myattribute="bar">i am some text<aninnertag>false</aninnertag> 
(more text specific stuff <atag>woot</atag>) 
and (another section <atag>woot again</atag> etc)
</foo>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to build this in dom4j. I could add elements for the inner tags but it's not going to generate it in a meaningful context. I could add it all as text but tags would get escaped.

How would one implement something like this in dom4j? Is it even possible?

This xml is terrible and I can't change it.

This is obviously incorrect in terms of output, but a basic example:

```
Element foo = new DefaultElement("foo");
foo.addText("i am some text" + "(more text specific stuff " + ")" + "and (another section "+ " etc)");
foo.addElement("aninnertag").addText("false");
foo.addElement("atag").addText("woot");
foo.addElement("atag").addText("woot again");
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write one `addText()` followed by three `addElement()` calls you will get an XML content where you have the text at the beginning and the XML elements at the end. You have to interleave the `addText()` and `addElement()` calls like this:

```
Element foo = new DefaultElement("foo");
foo.addAttribute("myattribute", "bar");
foo.addText("i am some text");
foo.addElement("aninnertag").addText("false");
foo.addText("(more text specific stuff ");
foo.addElement("atag").addText("woot");
foo.addText(") and (another section ");
foo.addElement("atag").addText("woot again");
foo.addText(" etc)");
System.out.println(foo.asXML());
```

This will generate the following output:

```
<foo myattribute="bar">i am some text<aninnertag>false</aninnertag>
(more text specific stuff <atag>woot</atag>) and (another section
<atag>woot again</atag> etc)</foo>
```